# natural isomorphisms

Tags: proof-explanation, homotopy-theory, model-categories, fibration

In the snippet below (taken from Hovey's MC book), I would like to understand in some detail
the lemma 6.1.2 (what it says) and the proof of it. Its too sketchy for me.
I do not even know what is Map$_{*\ell}(A,Y)$ there.
[image]

Comment: $Map_{*l}(A,Y)$ appears to be defined in the third paragraph of $\S5.7$. What is your actual question?

Comment: @Tyrone That's good. How is Map$_{*\ell}(A,Y)$ an **adjoint**; adjoint to what ? In that third paragraph of $\S$5.7. he uses $A$ which drops $*$ from the second paragraph. Also, the proof is a big computation (a chain of $\cong$) which I'm uable to follow.

Comment: Two-variable adjunctions are defined on pg. 106. I've never read past chptr 3, so I don't know what a framing is. I'm assuming that the isomorphisms are just the definitions of the various objects together with the (co)fibrancy observations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A bit on the definitions/background facts**

As has been pointed out in the comments, $\newcommand\Map{\operatorname{Map}}\Map_{*\ell}$ is defined at the beginning of section 5.7.

You ask in the comments about what $\Map_{*\ell}$ is adjoint to, and the answer is that we have the following (Quillen) adjunction:
$\Map_{*\ell}(A,-) : \newcommand\C{\mathcal{C}}\C\to\newcommand\sSet{\mathbf{sSet}}\sSet_*$ is right adjoint to $A\wedge - : \sSet_*\to\C$.

On the homotopical level, we have $R\Map_{*\ell}\cong R\Map_{*r}$, and the previous adjunction combines with the adjunction where $\newcommand\Hom{\operatorname{Hom}}\Hom(-,Y)$ is left adjoint to $\Map_{*r}(-,Y)$ adjunction to give an adjunction of 2-variables on the homotopical level (I won't need the adjunction of 2-variables part though).

Now as to how you should think of $\Map_{*\ell}(A,Y)$, that's another question entirely.
I recommend the following: $\Map_{*\ell}(A,Y)$ is the pointed simplicial set $(\Map_\ell(A,Y),0)$.

**The proof, using these facts**

Then we have the following chain of natural isomorphisms
$$
\newcommand\Ho{\operatorname{Ho}}
\Ho\C(\Sigma^tA,Y)\simeq
\Ho\C(A\wedge^L S^t,Y)
\simeq 
\Ho\sSet^*(S^t,R\Map_{*\ell}(A,Y)).
$$
The first natural isomorphism is associativity of $\wedge^L S^1$, since the $t$th smash power of $S^1$ is isomorphic to $S^t$ in the homotopy category.
The next natural isomorphism is the derived adjunction between $A\wedge -$ and $\Map_{*\ell}(A,-)$.
We also have the dual series of natural isomorphisms:
$$
\newcommand\Ho{\operatorname{Ho}}
\Ho\C(A,\Omega^tY)\simeq
\Ho\C(A, R\Hom(S^t, Y))
\simeq 
\Ho\sSet^*(S^t,R\Map_{*r}(A,Y)),
$$

Finally, as mentioned above, $R\Map_{*r}\simeq R\Map_{*\ell}$, so we can join these chains together to get the claimed series of isomorphisms, noting that for $M$ fibrant, we have
$\pi_tM\simeq\Ho\sSet^*(S^t,M)$, and it turns out $\Map_{*\ell}(A,Y)$ and $\Map_{*r}(A,Y)$ are fibrant when $A$ is cofibrant and $Y$ is fibrant.

**End note**

For more details on $\Map_{*\ell}$, $\Map_{*r}$, $\Hom$, and $\wedge$, I recommend reading chapter 5 and make sure you understand the "nerve/realization" adjoint construction, which appears to be in chapter 3, as well as how to apply it when we are working with categories enriched over $\mathbf{Set}_*$ (pointed categories).

Comment: OK. It's a good explanation. But why do you have everywhere $A$ where Hovey has $A^*$ ?

Comment: @user122424 Hovey uses $A^*$ to denote a cosimplicial frame on $A$, and $A^\circ$ to denote a specific functorial frame he constructs in chapter 5. Then we use these to define $\operatorname{Map}_{*\ell}(A,Y)[n]:=\mathcal{C}(A^\circ[n],Y)$, but once we've defined these things and proven their properties, we can avoid having to mess with the details of the framings as much as possible.

Comment: Where on page 144 he uses $A^\circ$ ? I cannot find it.

Comment: @user122424 Yeah it doesn't appear as notation, he cites the Theorem where he constructs the functorial frame. At the start of the third paragraph on p144, he writes "By Remark 3.1.7, the framing of Theorem 5.2.8 induces a bifunctor[...]" Theorem 5.2.8 is the Theorem where he constructs $A^\circ$.